# Using JS to write a noscript tag

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there any practical reason why you would write out a `<noscript>` tag with JavaScript's `document.write()`? Our ad department has been doing this for years and still does it after I've pointed it out. I'm 99% certain that this is due to an ancient ad template written by someone who didn't know what he was doing and no one has thought to change it because, "why fix what ain't broke?" Or maybe someone is reading their "best practices" wrong ("Always include a  alternative for browsers that have JS disabled"). Or maybe there's a really good reason I don't know about.

The only conceivable thing I can think of is that you could use it to modify the DOM without it appearing visible on the page and maybe use that content like a template for later use, but this seems pretty far-fetched.

(edit)

The  tag in this case contains a standard `<a href="/path/to/advertiser"><img src="/path/to/image" /></a>`. Because this is what the original, non-dynamic ad tag would have looked like, this makes me think this is just copy-pasted garbage.

The other thing I should say is that the reason I'm not 100% sure this is an oversite is because of the recent pattern of putting html templates inside `<script type="text/x-my-custom-template">...</script>`. I'm sceptical that someone on our end would have come up with this on their own, but it could have been a standard ad practice by someone with unusual cleverness.

Comment: How could you create a tag noscript with Javascript, if the same is disabled?

Comment: What's the content of the `<noscript>` tag?

Comment: Please tell me the <noscript> tag contains a "alert('please enable javascript');"

Comment: Isn't that like saying to someone, "I don't speak English"...in English?

Comment: @MarkLinus, maybe the point is to target users with JS enabled.

Comment: @EliotBonneville, I've updated the question. Tremmors, sadly, no, but that would be awesome. j08691, I live in Japan and hear that daily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any practical reason why you would write out a `<noscript>` tag with JavaScript's `document.write()`

Nope. The two (`<script>` and `<noscript>`) are mutually exclusive. It's like writing a piece of code like this:

```
if (true && false) {
    // do something important
}
```

---

If JavaScript is enabled, the browser ignores the `<noscript>` tag. On the other hand, if JavaScript is disabled, the `<noscript>` tag will never be written, because the `<script>` tag is ignored.

Comment: Not the same at all.  In your example, the `// do something important` is never reached. But if I run this on our home page, `document.getElementsByTagName('noscript').length;`, I get "3". The DOM is being updated. It is "running".

Comment: I think you misunderstood the pseudocode analogy: `// do something important` is analogous to what's _in_ the `<noscript>` tags. Sure, they are part of the DOM and as such can be queried using JS just like any other tag. There's no _point_ in having them in the DOM, because the browser disregards the content when rendering the page.

Comment: No, I understood that. I agree that the contents of the `<noscript>` is dead content as far as the HTML rendering engine is concerned, but  it's not dead to the DOM and it's not unreadable to JavaScript. Like my update says, the reason I'm asking this is that until recently, I'd not known that developers were using `<script>` tags to deliver view templates (e.g. [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)). In our case, it's probably a mistake, but it could actually be an actual modern technique.

Comment: sorry for not accepting earlier. I was hoping someone else might chime in with a rational explanation. But I think you'd agree there probably isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

This is used for bot detection / fingerprinting.

For example if I use

```
document.write('<script src='...'>...</script><noscript><img>....</noscript>');
```

Chrome 55+ blocks not same origin scripts written from `document.write()`.  This means the above `<noscript>` actually will run on certain/newer versions of chrome despite coming from a "script".

The assumed purpose is if the bot is pretending to be for example (via spoofing its user agent) a specific version of chrome, and the script is not blocked, it would point to the fact that its not *really* chrome (bot).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I asked this five years ago when Chrome was at version 18 and was only just reaching parity with IE and, as I said the ad department had been doing it for years. Now that I no longer work with these guys, I think I can safely say that the ad department had no idea what they were doing and were "cargo-culting" their way through their job. That said, I do appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can add child node in a specific html tags.

```
var noscript = document.createElement('noscript')
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
iframe.setAttribute('src', "<your source>")
iframe.setAttribute("height", "0")
iframe.setAttribute("width", "0")
iframe.setAttribute("style", "display:none;visibility:hidden")
noscript.appendChild(iframe)
document.body.appendChild(noscript)
```